# c# Why does my page / user control only support one event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

I have 2 events that I want to fire from a user control back to it's parent.
"UserSelected" and "NoUsersSelected"

One fires when a user is selected and the other fires when all the users have been removed.

My problem is "UserSelected" works, but "NoUsersSelected" fails... In the code snippets below, I have commented the line that fails.

**UPDATE:**
When I comment all code relating to the first event handler, the 2nd one starts working.

Here is the code on my child (user) control:

```
    public event EventHandler UserSelected;
    public event EventHandler NoUsersSelected;

    protected virtual void onUserSelected(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (UserSelected != null) UserSelected(this, e);
        }

    protected virtual void onNoUsersSelected(System.EventArgs e)
        {

**###** PROBLEM ! - NoUsersSelected is always null so doesn't fire event **###**
            if (NoUsersSelected != null) NoUsersSelected(this, e);
        }
```

And to raise the events, I use buttons inside a GridView TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' CommandName="SelectUser" ToolTip="Select User" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="GridBtn_Select" CausesValidation="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' CommandName="DeleteUser" ToolTip="Delete User" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="GridBtn_Delete" CausesValidation="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And here is the code behind for these buttons:

```
if (e.CommandName == "SelectUser")
        {onUserSelected(System.EventArgs.Empty);}
```

and...

```
if (e.CommandName == "DeleteUser")
        { //this is where I remove the user from the grid...

            if (gridUsers.Rows.Count < 1)
                {onNoUsersSelected(System.EventArgs.Empty);}
```

.

On the parent page that hosts the user control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Bind to the event on child control
            GridAdvertiserUsers.UserSelected += UserSelected_EventHandler;
            GridAdvertiserUsers.NoUsersSelected += NoUsersLinked_EventHandler;
}
```

and the functions that the events call:

```
  void UserSelected_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { //do stuff here }

  void NoUsersLinked_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { //Do other stuff }
```

**UPDATE:**

When onUserSelected is called, both Events seem to have their methods wired up correctly
 [image: When onUserSelected is called, both Events seem to have their methods wired up correctly]

But when onNoUserSelected is called, they are both null:
[image: when onNoUserSelected is called, they are both null]

Comment: Is there any difference between the two buttons (the things that fire the commands)?

Comment: Good question Maarten !
I will update my original question to show the html for the buttons I am using.

Comment: Still no closer to a solution,  can anyone help ??